# How do I get multiple rectangular thumbnail sizes in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, size, thumbnails, rectangles

This may sound like a silly question but I've struggled to find the answer elsewhere.

I'm trying to get a few different (rectangular) sizes of thumbnail on my Wordpress.org homepage. Currently all I get are squares (or sometimes, bizarrely, one or two rectangles and the rest squares).

I'm using this code in `<head>`:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

...and this in The Loop:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(90,60), $attr ); ?>
```

I've also tried using this in `<head>`:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 180, 80, true );
add_image_size( 'worth-reading', 180, 80 );
```

...and this in The Loop:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'worth-reading' ); ?>
```

With both of these methods I've tried uploading new Featured Images *after* coding the above in (and also using the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin).

Anyway, the above includes everything I've found on similar forum posts and still none of it seems to work.

Many thanks in advance!

---

many thanks for your help!

I've done exactly as you said and unfortunately it still doesn't entirely work.

The normal thumbnails are now the correct size but the additional image sizes are just squares with the specified height.

In functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 90, 60, true );

    // Examples of additional image sizes
    add_image_size( 'latest', 120, 100 );
    add_image_size( 'worth-reading', 180, 80 );
}
```

...and at various point in the body:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

&

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'latest' ); ?>
```

&

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'worth-reading' ); ?>
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, but enabling the support for featured images and registering sizes needs to be done in your functions.php

So in functions.php add this:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 180, 80, true ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions (cropped)

    // Examples of additional image sizes
    // add_image_size( 'worth-reading', 180, 80 ); 
}
```

Since you are setting the default post_thumbnail_size to 180x80 - you probably don't need to register another custom size using the same dimensions but I left an example (commented out) of how you would do it.

In the loop you would use this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

**Regenerate thumbnails has problems with custom sizes**. It will only resize media library items using the sizes defined in the media settings (Settings -> Media). For older posts, I usually just re-upload the image once I add the new size.

Source is all here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for your help!

I've done exactly as you said and unfortunately it still doesn't work. 

- See my reply! :)

Comment: Could be, can you share a URL? I'd like to see what is being output.

Answer (score 0):

Something to note about the add_image_size field. The functions works like this:

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

$name is your custom name, $width is width, $height is height. Crop by default is false (which is how you are using it), which will try it's best to crop / resize the photo. If you set it to true it will hard crop the image without trying to resize it.  This is more FYI.

The code you are using SHOULD be working. WordPress only creates the image sizes when you upload the image. Plugins like regenerate thumbnails won't actually create the image size for custom added image sizes.

Did you re-upload the images after moving this code into functions.php?

Comment: I did, which is why I'm so confused!

I'm using the Starkers theme – could it be that this doesn't use those functions correctly?